# How to use the completeCallback in the play-function of native audio in Ionic?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I want to play an other sound after one is done with playing. Native audio has the perfect function for it but how can i the completeCallback part.
[Native Audio Play-Function](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-audio/#play)

```
  this.nativeAudio.play('sound', () => {console.log("play done!")});
```

Example is with console.log(). After playing i dont get a message in the Console.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Answer (score 0):

I use Ionic Native - Media now. It has more features to control the status of the Audiofile! So i could run the Audiofile in a loop with Cordova Media.

Following this tutorial and documentaion:

[Youtube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4DLrvWEj_o)

[Cordova Documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-media/)

[Ionic Native Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/)